# Ejecutar función de mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Vengo por aquí para una ayuda ya que no poseo casi nada de conocimiento en la programación. Tengo este código el cual funciona a la perfección cuando entro 5 dígitos automáticamente actualiza la página, pero también me gustaría que cuando actualice la pagina haga la siguiente función de MySQL.

```
$mysql_query("Insert IGNORE into voters
Select * from barcode where id = escoger el numero de id;
DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)")
```

```
<?php
    include 'includes/conn.php';
    include 'includes/scripts.php'; 


    if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
        $sca=trim($_POST['no'],"");     
        $flag=0;
        $id="";
        $credentials="";
        $password="";
        $firstname="";
        $lastname="";
        $new2 ="SELECT * FROM `barcode`";
        $res2=mysqli_query($conn, $new2);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
                    if($row['credentials'] == $sca){
                        $flag=1;
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $credentials=$row['credentials'];
                        $password=$row['password'];
                        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
                        $lastname=$row['lastname'];
                    }       
    }

    if ($flag==1) {$mysqli -> query("Insert IGNORE into voters
Select * from barcode where id = escoger el numero de id;
DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)");

            echo
                header("refresh: .5");
   }

   else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center mt-3'>Product Not Found</div></div>";    
                return;
            }
    }

mysqli_close($conn);
 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que cuando hagas un refresh de la página, en vez de hacerlo de la manera que lo haces, te redireccione a la misma página y le pases una variable:

```
header("Location: .$index.php?redireccion=si");
```

Luego dentro de tu código html, dberás de crear una comprobación para ver si esta variable existe, y en tal caso llamar a la consulta que desees:

```
if(isset($_GET['redireccion'])){
    
    if($_GET['redireccion'] == 'si'){

       // LO QUE DESEES HACER AQUÍ

    }
}
```

Comment: Sería de esta manera?

 if ($flag==1) {
            echo
                header("Location: .$match.php?redireccion=si");

                if(isset($_GET['redireccion'])){
    
                    if($_GET['redireccion'] == 'si'){

                        $mysqli_query("Insert IGNORE into voters
                        Select * from barcode where id = escoger el numero de id;
                        DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters");
                        // LO QUE DESEES HACER AQUÍ
                    }
                }

Comment: La consulta la tienes que hacer de la misma manera que haces la otra consulta, solo que tendrás que adaptarla para que haga lo que necesitas, y tendrás que añadrila en el sitio mencionado. En lo que tu me has puesto, veo que compruebas ` if ($flag==1) `, que no se exactamente para que lo utilizas, pero si quieres que entre cuando se actualiza la página, y este valor no es 1, no te servirá de nada lo que pongas dentro Un saludo